# Amending the local commit after rebase in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, mercurial-hook, mercurial-extension

In the beginning, my local repo looked like:
`C1 -> C2 -> My1` 
and the remote repository looked like:
`C1 -> C2 -> R1 -> R2`
So I did:
`$ hg pull`
`$ hg rebase`
Now the repo looks like:
`C1 -> C2 -> R1 -> R2 -> My1`

Now I have made some changes to a file "File1.java" and want these changes to be a part of the last commit `My1`. When I do a:
`$ hg commit File1.java --amend`
the error message I get is:
`abort: cannot amend merge changesets`
On googling I found [this](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2012-February/037810.html), according to which it looks like an issue in mercurial but I am sure there is a way around it.
Please tell me the set of steps to amend the new changes in the last local commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like My1 is a merge but your diagram does not highlight that at all. Can you check the state of your repo with:

```
hg log --graph
```

If My1 is a merge (and you expected it to be merge). Mercurial 2.6 should be able to edit a merge changeset. So if you upgrade to Mercurial 2.6.1 or above your original command will work.

```
   hg commit --amend  File1.java
```

Comment: Thanks Marmoute. It worked. I'm not sure why but it looked like a merge in hg graph. I had to use: https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases to install Mercurial 2.6 in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Was the `My1` changeset a merge changeset before rebasing? rebase does attempt to preserve the number of parents between branches (you can see Section 10 under [rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) for more info).

Assuming that you haven't pushed your changeset (i.e. it still has a phase of `draft` using `hg phase`) and you are willing to use hg's patch extension `mq`, you can do it thus:

```
hg qimport -r tip
hg qrefresh 
hg qfinish -a
```

This imports the `tip` changeset into the patch queue and then updates that patch to include the current changes in the working directory. Finally, it moves the (now updated) changeset back into the repo, ready to go.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used the mq extensions yet but it seems to be a very powerful tool.